# PHP Specify access to build in functions

Tags: php

Is there any way to lock access to some built-in php functions, eg `rmdir()`, and make permission to some other function/method/object to access it?

Comment: Would be good to understand why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override functions with [runkit_function_redefine](https://www.php.net/runkit_function_redefine), but you must also set `runkit.internal_override` in php.ini otherwise you can only override functions in user space.

Once you have overridden `rmdir()` you can make it do anything you want: Do nothing, only work in certain directories, only work when there is a session variable set, etc...

I haven't tried [ADP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) before, but you could also use [override_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) and [rename_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php). You could rename `rmdir()` to `rmdir_hidden()` and override the built-in name to call the new name given certain conditions. It would still be possible to call `rmdir_hidden()`, but only *if* the coder knows what it has been renamed to.

By the way - I don't think it's really a good idea to be redefining built-in functions in PHP. Maybe before you implement this, you should take a good look at what you are doing and why you're doing it. In all the PHP projects I've worked on, I've never seen or considered overriding a built-in function.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Check the disable_functions property:

> disable_functions
>
> This directive allows you to disable certain
> functions for security reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of
> function names. disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode.
>
> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
> User-defined functions are unaffected.
>
> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this
> in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `disable_functions` [configuration parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). But once a function is disabled via this route, it cannot be enabled again.

Beyond that, you cannot restrict access to any of the built-in functions in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Look for disable_functions in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

disable_functions is global so I advise using it only as a last resort.

In the case of rmdir() and other file system functions you could make sure that the user PHP is running under (probably apache) does not have the permissions to modify files and folders you don't want it to.

As a more general consideration. If you are allowing people you don't trust to execute code you might want to reconsider your design!